# How to work with Storyboard Unwind Segue in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, storyboard

I have a good understanding how to work with Storyboard, Segues and Unwind-Segues on iOS. For porting my App to OS X I need to rewrite the UI and want to do this with the OS X storyboards. However the Unwinding-Mechanism from iOS seems not be the same like in iOS. How to Unwind a ViewController-Scene on Mac OS X. Where is that "Exit"-Button in the ViewController ?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike iOS where the screen is the real estate. In Mac, we have plenty of space. You see, from the builtin segues, most of them are just a way to show up a new dialog. And, when you are done with it. You don't really need to go back somewhere, all you need is a way to close that dialog down.

To decoupling things a bit further, instead of unwinding which require selector from other view controller. They encourage us to use `dismissController:` from the view controller we want to close it down. This method will dismiss the view controller using the same segue animator that presented it.

```
-(IBAction)backDidTap:(id)sender {
    [self dismissController: nil];
}
```

In other words, this is one step unwinding.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I have a NSViewController subclass which I set in Interface Builder. When closing the view controllers window or when calling dismissController the -(void)dealloc is not being called! I haven't instanciated the VC anywhere else in code. Just in IB. On iOS it is a bit the same. Only when using unwind segues the View Controllers are being proper deallocated ... So I end up in a memory leak on OS X ...

Comment: It's hard to say why your VC did not get released. There could be many reasons. But, if you are using the latest Xcode. I don't think it's your fault at all.

Comment: how do we pass data back this way?